# How can I draw the equilibrium line from the graph of a Simple Harmonic Motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I have been been having this problem. I was at the laboratory and performed experiments on simple harmonic motion. The data paper gave me this image which depicts the movement across time:

[image]

Is there any method that can be used to draw the line in the middle, the line that shows the equilibrium. How can I get to the picture here below (drawing the horizontal line)

[image]

Comment: Is this really a simple harmonic motion? It looks damped over time. Anyway, is the goal only to find the mathematical limit of a function? In this case the math forum is more adequate.

Comment: Yes. The goal is SOLELY to graph the horizontal line in the second figure right away, geometrically.

Comment: You could use curve-fitting software to fit the function $f(t) = A\sin(b t) e^{-ct} + d$, then once you find the best fit value of $d$, the line $y=d$ would be your line. Is that what you're looking for? That assumes that the system is purely a damped harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Looks to me that it's the *average* of the values that's being plotted...